# Is it possible to send output to a variable in bash?

Tags: bash, copy

I have result of simple command:

```
   cp -R SourceDir DestDir >out.txt
   result="out.txt"
```

But if script haven't access to write, how I can get output in variable result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
result=$(cp -R SourceDir DestDir)
```

You can also use this form:

```
result=`cp -R SourceDir DestDir`
```

but this is less preferable for several reasons (see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).

Answer (score 2):

```
result=$(cp -R SourceDir DestDir)
echo $result
```

Answer (score 1):

By using backticks (`):

```
OUTPUT=`cp -R SourceDir DestDir`
```

Or did I get you wrong?

Comment: In general, `$(...)` should be preferred to backticks; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082.